# jQuery upload file field click and submit erasing field value

Tags: jquery, html

One more time FF/Chrome/Safari works... but IE doesn´t... depressing but a reality.

Here´s the deal. I have a nice looking page with a simple file field visually hidden (opacity, not display) and here is my workflow :

- user clicks on a nice graphic
- I trigger the click event of the file field.
- the file dialog opens
- user selects file
- user then clicks on a nice graphic to submit the form
- the end

In IE right after the form submit event is triggered the field is magically emptied and the submit event is not completed. Its as if the event only erases the field and nothing more!!!

Here is the JS code :

```
$('#file_browse').bind('click', function() {
    $('#file_field').trigger('click');
});

$('#file_form #file_field').bind('change', function() {
    $('#file_submit').show();
});

$('#file_form #file_submit').bind('click', function() {
    $('#file_form').submit();
});
```

That´s it! The html has a simple file field. Nothing special. I tested without any css on the input field and it happens right in front of me... the field is emptied out.

Anybody has a clue as why this happens???